# Create CMYK PDF from Inkscape SVG with 100% Magenta "cutkontur"

Tags: printing, pdf, inkscape

I designed a sticker to be cut free-form. The printer asks:

> Please note: 
>   For the contour cut we need a vectorized contour line from you in the pdf > print file. Please color this line with a solid color, which you call cut > contour and which consists of 100 percent magenta.

Can I create such from Inkscape / and / or with Linux tools ?

EDIT: I found this https://www.klaasnotfound.com/2016/06/05/creating-cmyk-prepress-pdfs-with-inkscape-and-scribus/ ... wondering if I just have to name my Magenta from the SVG "cutkontur" and I am all set?

Comment: Ah... you are also using *wir-machen-druck.de* ?  ;-)

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Genau! :-) In the meantime I got the delivery and the result was fine - so I think the method described here is valid.

Comment: Yes, it certainly is. Which is why I upvoted your own answer to the question. *wir-machen-druck.de* certainly deliver good print quality and are not expensive either. I also recently printed a few of similar things as you (*"Hochwertige Etiketten auf Rolle in Frei-Form (alle Stanzformen möglich)"*), which is why 'cutcontour' immediately rang a bell in my head :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the guide in

https://www.klaasnotfound.com/2016/06/05/creating-cmyk-prepress-pdfs-with-inkscape-and-scribus/

- Save in Inkscape
- Set Color Management in Scribus
- Open File
- Edit Colors
- Convert Magenta to CMYK pure Magenta and set the color name "cutkontur"

[image: Screenshot]